# jQuery.dequeue recursion order

Tags: jquery

The dequeue function has the following recursive structure. I thought the nested `dequeue` call should occur before `fn`, thus will it still maintain the FIFO order?

```
dequeue: function( elem, type ) {
            fn.call(elem, function() {jQuery.dequeue(elem, type);

    })
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: which version of jQuery is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the complete code(below), `fn` is the first item in the queue list(since [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) is used `fn = queue.shift()`), so you need to invoke the `fn` first.

had we used [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)(which will give the last item in the array), we would have to call `dequeue()` then invoke `fn`

```
dequeue: function( elem, type ) {
    type = type || "fx";

    var queue = jQuery.queue( elem, type ),
        fn = queue.shift(),
        defer;

    // If the fx queue is dequeued, always remove the progress sentinel
    if ( fn === "inprogress" ) {
        fn = queue.shift();
    }

    if ( fn ) {
        // Add a progress sentinel to prevent the fx queue from being
        // automatically dequeued
        if ( type === "fx" ) {
            queue.unshift("inprogress");
        }

        fn.call(elem, function() {
            jQuery.dequeue(elem, type);
        });
    }

    if ( !queue.length ) {
        jQuery.removeData( elem, type + "queue", true );
        handleQueueMarkDefer( elem, type, "queue" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arun for taking the time to answer. But fn in invoked like fn.call(elem, function() {
        jQuery.dequeue(elem, type);   }); does it mean that the next dequeue should be executed first?

Comment: `fn.call()` is invoking `fn` when that is completed, the second argument(I think it is a callback function) will get called which is calling the dequeue again